# Change color from another class is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I try to change the color of a canvas by pressing a button using command binding insted of click event to avoid any code behind in the MyView.xaml.cs file. The command is fireing and the messageboxes show the correct color code values before and after changing it so the new color is set but the color of the canvas do not change. If a use a click event and the code behind in the MyView.xaml.cs insted than all work fine but I would like to get it work wiht command bindning and without code behind in the MyView.xaml.cs file. How can I do that and what is that I am not doing right?

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:View="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.View"
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="YellowGreen" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:MyClass/>
  </Window.DataContext>

  <View:MyView/>
</Window>
```

MyView.xaml file

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.View.MyView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.ViewModel"
         xmlns:View="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.View">

  <Canvas Name="MainCanvas" Height="300" Width="502" Background="#FF148B63">
    <Button Name="ChangeColorButton" Command="{Binding CommandChangeColor}" Content="new color" Height="25" Width="55" Margin="225,268,225,10"/>
  </Canvas> 
</UserControl>
```

MyClass.cs

```
public class MyClass : MyView
{
 List<Color> _listOfColors = new List<Color>();
 public MyClass(){ MyInitColor(); }

 public ICommand CommandChangeColor
 {
      get { return new MyCommand(ChangeColor); }
 }

 public void ChangeColor()
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Color before: " + MainCanvas.Background.ToString());

     Random rnd = new Random();
     int i = rnd.Next(_listOfColors.Count - 1);
     MainCanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(_listOfColors[i]);

     MessageBox.Show("Color after: " + MainCanvas.Background.ToString());
 }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can have many instances of a UserControl, how would MyClass know which instance of MainCanvas it should be updating?
So similar to your binding for CommandChangeColor you should also bind the Background to some property in MyClass. Something like:

Xaml:

```
<Canvas Name="MainCanvas" Height="300" Width="502" Background="{Binding BackGroundColor}">
  <Button Name="ChangeColorButton" Command="{Binding CommandChangeColor}" Content="new color" Height="25" Width="55" Margin="225,268,225,10"/>
</Canvas>
```

MyClass.cs

```
public SolidColorBrush BackGroundColor {get;set;}

public void ChangeColor()
{
   MessageBox.Show("Color before: " + MainCanvas.Background.ToString());

   Random rnd = new Random();
   int i = rnd.Next(_listOfColors.Count - 1);
   BackGroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(_listOfColors[i]);

   MessageBox.Show("Color after: " + MainCanvas.Background.ToString());
}
```

You will probably also want to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Ty, I did like you suggested and used a property and binded the background color to taht and worked perfect :) Have only one more question because I am new here. How can I mark your answer as the correct one?

Comment: just click the tick sign on the left side of his answer.

Comment: Nvm I fined out how to do that :)